# Jest NPM: Ignore single line

Tags: node.js, jestjs

Node v10.1.0

I am trying to ignore a single line in my code when using Jest to test my functions and tried the solution below:

```
/* istanbul ignore next */ App.init();
```

When I run npm test, it still executes this line of code. Is there a solution to this that I am missing? I've been looking around the docs with no luck.

Comment: You may have XY problem. There could be different entry points for different purposes. In one (production) you initialize the app and in another (tests) you don't. This depends on where exactly this line occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/* istanbul ignore next */` is intended to ignore the next line for *code coverage*; Jest [uses Istanbul](https://istanbul.js.org/docs/tutorials/jest/) for code coverage.

There is no magical way how line can be not evaluated in tests. A preferable way to do this depends on specific case.

For example, it can be environment-dependent:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test')
  App.init();
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much.